# Why does jQuery slide down corrupt my embedded YouTube players in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

Please see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmhHd/1/

Click the link to have the embedded player slide down. In my Chrome browser, the video is displayed as either a green or black box. It appears to work fine in Firefox.

Is there a way to get around this / should I be doing this another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's weird is if you refresh the page once you click the link, you'll see green and then the video loads. Maybe there's another event you need to trigger via callback once the slidedown is complete. What happens if you it the long way using animate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way: http://jsfiddle.net/PcfQY/.
It works for me.